# how to add reg_multi_sz value in VS 2008 setup project registry editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

how can i add reg_multi_sz values into registry from a setup project installer in vs 2008?
the only options they have are string value, environment string value, binary value, dword value
help, please

Answer (score 3):

Enter it as a regular string value and separate your multiple strings with this: [~] and when it's installed it will be set as a REG_MULTI_SZ.

Comment: This is a correct answer. If one looks for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/msi/registry-table?redirectedfrom=MSDN